# Counting the number of times a string appears in a range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Quite new to programming and have gotten stuck after much searching.
I'm trying to make a Google script that can search a particular column and count how many times values 'YES' or 'NO' appear in the column (after that it would act based on those numbers).

Tried various ways to do this but all unsuccessful, what I think is the closest example is below:

```
   function billChecker() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 var values = sheet.getSheetValues(3, 5, 20, 1);
 Logger.log(values);

  var unpaidEntries = values.indexOf("YES"); 

 var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  var subject = "Test";

  var body = "The number of unpaid items is " + unpaidEntries + "." + "The values contained are: " + values;

 GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body);
}
```

As you can tell, the purpose of the script is to say how many unpaid bills there are, I am emailing myself results, it's the only way I can think to check it at the moment!
I thought the best way to do it was probably to use example.indexOf() method, however that always produces '-1'.

Answer (score 2):

The method `getSheetValues` returns a **double** array: an array in which each element is an array of elements in the corresponding row. 
For example, if the range is filled with

```
1 2
3 4
```

you are going to get `[[1,2], [3,4]]`. If the range has just one column, as in your example, this structure still applies:

```
1
3
```

is represented as `[[1], [3]]`.

So, you are never going to find a string "YES" as an element of an array, since there would be `["YES"]` instead. Additionally, `indexOf` is meant for finding the **first** occurrence of some value, not for counting them. Here is how you can count them:

```
var unpaid = values.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + (b[0] == 'YES' ? 1 : 0);
}, 0);
```

Here, `a` is the counter, initially set to 0.  The [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method traverses the `values` array, serving up each of its elements, such as `["YES"]` or `["NO"]`, as the argument `b`. The reducing function adds 1 to the counter when `b[0]` is "YES".

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! Explanation is very useful. I had a feeling it was returning something other than a regular array but couldn't work out how to find out.. Documentation didn't really clear it up (to me at least). How are you able to tell?

Comment: Debugging commands such as  `Logger.log(values);` (which writes into log, accessible via menu) can be useful. And Documentation does say "Return Object[][] — a two dimension array of values"

Answer (score 2):

Use this code that I made. It does exactly what you're looking for:

Sample data:

```
Range Start: A5 (5,1)
```

[image]

```
function countRepitition() {

   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ENTER_SPREADSHEET_ID");
   var sheetname = ss.getSheetByName("ENTER_SHEET_NAME");

   var count = 0;
   var values = sheetname.getRange(5, 1, 9, 2).getValues(); //Start of Range (5,1) -> A5, End of Range (9,2) -> B9

   for (var row in values) {
     for (var col in values[row]) {

       if (values[row][col] == "YES") {
         count++; //increment count everytime we find the string 'YES' upon given range
       }

     }
   }

  Logger.log('count is '+ count); //print the valuoe of count in the Logs
}
```

This is the result in the console:

[image]